# Does slime-repl-ansi-color work at all these days?

Tags: ansi-term, slime

I was unable to make it display ansi colorized output in Lisp REPL despite this project claims.

https://github.com/deadtrickster/slime-repl-ansi-color

The code seemingly doesn't do anything except setting a variable. However in my slime folder `.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20170319.1601` doesn't seem to contain anything slime-repl-ansi-color could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still works. You need to have the file in the `contrib` directory under `.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20170319.1601`, then do something like

```
(push 'slime-repl-ansi-color slime-contribs)
(slime-setup)
```

to enable it.

It interfaces with `slime` through the `slime-repl-emit` function.

Comment: I have downloaded the file https://github.com/deadtrickster/slime-repl-ansi-color/blob/master/slime-repl-ansi-color.el and copied it to my contrib folder /home/jacek/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20170929.1441/contrib

Comment: Then I have added your code sample to my Emacs startup file. Now I have coloured output in slime.

Comment: https://melpa.org/#/slime-repl-ansi-color would be better but for the bug which starts out with colors disabled until you do `M-x slime-repl-ansi-color-mode RET` in the REPL buffer.